# How to get the categories and its relevant data in a JSON using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to get job titles and its related data such as areas and subareas. My JSON is here

```
{ "data":[{"IT_JOBS":{ "areas": [ "SE", "QA","PM"],"subareas":["Associate","Trainee","Developer"] },..}] }
```

Comment: can you attach a plnkr?

Comment: Ok, what have you tried?

Comment: @Esko I used for in loop. How can get the value "IT_JOBS"?

Comment: Post your code in the question so that we can see what might be wrong.

Comment: Your data doesn't need to be wrapped in an array. An object would suffice for the job titles. The JS will look awkward because it will use `Object.keys()` or a `for..in` loop for something that only has one key.

Comment: @madhev In your code, `event` holds `IT_JOBS`. Do `'type'+event`. Please add your code to the question so that others can see what you had in your comment before it was deleted.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/yilujigati/1/edit?js,console

this will work if there is a single object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have an array of objects, you'll need to modify your data.

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "name": "IT_JOBS",
          "areas":[
             "SE",
             "QA",
             "PM"
          ],
          "subareas":[
             "Associate",
             "Trainee",
             "Developer"
          ]
      }, 
      {
         "name": "IT",
          "areas":[
             "SEs",
             "QsA",
             "PMs"
          ],
          "subareas":[
             "Assocsasdiate",
             "Traineeasd",
             "Developeasdasdr"
          ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is a sample [Jsfiddle](http://jsbin.com/gezayizihu/edit?js,console).

```
for (var key in response.data) {
  var obj = response.data[key];

  console.log("Values for ITEM: " + key)
  console.log("Name: " + obj.name);
  console.log("Areas: " + obj.areas);
  console.log("Subareas: " + obj.subareas);
}
```

If you have a single object, you can do something like this [Jsfiddle](http://jsbin.com/yilujigati/1/edit?js,console).

```
for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
  console.log("Values for IT_JOBS");
  console.log("Areas: " + response.data[i].IT_JOBS.areas);
  console.log("Subareas: " + response.data[i].IT_JOBS.subareas);
}
```